# Python excel two if conditions

Tags: excel, python-3.x

I did python script which updates prices in excel sheet and writes it in column 3:

[sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Clsue.png)

I do it this way:

```
 import os, openpyxl

    os.chdir('C:\\Users\\Tadas\\Documents\\Python_pvz')

    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('pardavimai_paprasti.xlsx')
    sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet')



    for rowNum in range(6, sheet.max_row):  
        customer = sheet.cell(row=rowNum, column=1).value
        article = sheet.cell(row=rowNum, column=2).value
        if customer == 242061 and article == '0288-0482':
           sheet.cell(row=rowNum, column=3).value = 1
        elif customer == 242061 and article == '0288-0757':
            sheet.cell(row=rowNum, column=3).value = 2 
        elif customer == 242061 and article == '1159-0757':
            sheet.cell(row=rowNum, column=3).value = 3


wb.save('updatedpardavimai.xlsx')
```

How can I improve code or I will have to copy these elif's till I will go crazy?

Comment: You could always properly connect your data source for column 3, look up the customer and article there and insert the price in a simple loop. If that's less work depends on how you hold your price data and how many rows you need to fill.